# What does Ritchie's 1979 PDP-11 `/usr/games/bcd` do?

Tags: history, games

I recently tried the simh emulator `pdp11`.

The disk image I used can be found on the internet, and instructions for booting it are [here](https://sites.google.com/site/jamestownson/unix-7-on-simh).

Presumably it belonged to Dennis Ritchie, as the username is "dmr".

In the /usr/games folder are about 20 games and amusements for wasting expensive computing resources.

One 'game' is called 'bcd'.

If I run it by typing `./bcd`, nothing happens. But then the next command I execute gets printed out as ascii art:

```
 ________________________________________________
/WC -L *                                         |
| ]                                              |
|   ]] ]                                         |
|]                                               |
|111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111|
|222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222|
|3]33]3333333333333333333333333333333333333333333|
|444444]44444444444444444444444444444444444444444|
|555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555|
|]66666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666|
|777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777|
|888888]88888888888888888888888888888888888888888|
|999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999|
|________________________________________________|



 ________________________________________________
/LS                                              |
|                                                |
|]                                               |
| ]                                              |
|111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111|
|2]2222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222|
|]33333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333|
|444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444|
|555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555|
|666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666666|
|777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777777|
|888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888|
|999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999|
|________________________________________________|
```

Does anyone know what these represent?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The `bcd` command formats the output as a [punch card](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punched_card), like this one:

[image]

From the [BSD games](http://wiki.linuxquestions.org/wiki/BSD_games) [man page](http://derpi.tuwien.ac.at/cgi-bin/man/man2html?bcd%206):

> bcd ppt morse - reformat input as punch cards, paper tape or morse code

The `]` stands for where the holes would be.

At first glance, it seems to do nothing because it's waiting for input from `stdin`. Try piping something into it (i.e. `command | bcd`) to see.

Comment: Since this appears to be a serious work tool I wonder why it was put in the games folder?

Comment: I don't really think this is a serious work tool; (I think that) in 1979 punch cards weren't used that much.

Comment: @DanNeely To make real punch cards, you need a card punch. printing them is just pretty.

Comment: I wonder which coding it uses...

Comment: @sendmoreinfo: Probably [BCD coding](http://homepage.cs.uiowa.edu/~jones/cards/codes.html).