# Is cdimage.debian.org running UNIX?

Tags: apache-httpd

I recentlty visited the 'cdimage.debian.org' website and typed an incorrect URL. I obviously got a 404 error code; at the bottom of the Apache2 error page I saw this message:

> Apache/2.4.51 (Unix) Server at cdimage.debian.org Port 443

Apparently, the server is running on Unix; is that right? Is "real" UNIX (not a derivate unix-like os, like Minix or *BSD or GNU/Linux) still used in 2022? Are Debian's servers *really* running "pure" UNIX

EDIT: the full page looked like this:

## Not Found

The requested URL was not found on this server.

---

*Apache/2.4.51 (**Unix**) Server at cdimage.debian.org Port 443*

Comment: Since Apache is a project targeting both Unix and Windows, I believe they use the term "Unix" loosely to mean "anything Unix-like where Apache is running".  This would include Linux.  This is not an answer as I don't give any support for my claims.  Additionally, `nmap` guesses the system running at that host as "Linux".

Comment: See also [What is Unix now?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/14867) which this question may be a duplicate of. Summary: "Unix" today is a trademark/standard/certification, not any specific operating system.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Actually, when I run a apache2 server on Ubuntu, that page has "ubuntu" written instead of unix, and this happens also with other linuxes. But I didn't know about nmap...

Comment: Debian Apache also reports `Server: Apache/2.4.53 (Debian)`. I assume there is a custom build (ie someone built it from sources for some reason). I am pretty sure `debian.org` uses Debian

Comment: Details about that server cluster can be found at http://napoleon.ftp.acc.umu.se/about/

Comment: The server string is just an arbitrary string that doesn't really mean anything.  It is optional and can contain any value, or none.  It doesn't even mean that the server is really running Apache - any other httpd could claim to be Apache, and Apache could claim to be some other program.  Apache itself has [ServerSignature](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#serversignature) and [ServerTokens](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#servertokens) configuration directives to control what (if anything) it uses as the server string.