# Can I install proper Unix on my PC?

Tags: system-installation, distributions

Can I install Unix on my PC? I mean not Linux, nor BSD.

Although the name of this forum is Unix and Linux, most of the users seem to be running some flavour of Linux.

Comment: What are you looking for? Irix? AIX? Solaris? HP-UX?

Comment: The OS called Unix eventually divided into multiple variants over the course of its history. Today, you could pick one of these variants/derivatives and install it on your system. Wikipedia has a cool chart of this history: [Evolution of Unix and Unix-like systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Unix_history-simple.svg).

Comment: 1) define "Unix" :) 2) Define "PC" and how much hardware support you need (network (esp WiFi), bluetooth, audio, graphics...).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run Unix?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/252631/how-to-run-unix)

Comment: FTR, I voted for the dupe above, not “too broad”.

Comment: Please, define what *precisely* you mean by "Unix", and what *precisely* you mean by "PC". If by "Unix" you mean "the original OS named Unix written by Ken Thompson, Dennis Ritchie, Doug McIllroy, Joe Ossana et al in 1969 at Bell Labs", then no, you can't. That original version was written in PDP-7 assembly and only ran on a PDP-7. It was later ported to a PDP-11/20, but still written in assembly. If by "Unix" you mean "any OS that has passed the UNIX® testsuite and is certified UNIX®-compliant", then you can run Windows NT with SFU. If you mean "an OS that feels like Unix", then you can run …

Comment: That is kind of like requesting to interact with REAL *homo sapiens*, and NOT *European* or *American* or *African*  current-day human.... Original UNIX forked (and was reimplemented) many times since its inception. Today, it is [trademarked](http://www.unix.org/what_is_unix.html)   definition for all OSes that comply with Single UNIX Specification integrating X/Open Company's XPG4, IEEE's POSIX Standards and ISO C. (which GNU/Linux and BSD might do as well as others)

Comment: … pretty much any Linux distribution. If you mean "any OS that is derived directly from the original Unix sourcecode", then you can run any commercial Unix. If you mean "any OS that was developed based on the original Unix", then you can run any BSD. If by "PC" you mean "anything with an Intel processor", then you can run macOS on a Mac or IRIX on an Itanium machine.

Answer (score 3):

Absolutely, though there really isn't much reason to unless you have a specific need for one these days.  The reasons would generally be that you have specific hardware/software that only supports a particular implementation of Unix.  That's mostly legacy stuff these days as Linux / *BSD are the 'go to' platforms.  If you decide to do this just be aware: you won't gain very much and will lose a lot in terms of functionality and software availability.  Also, there isn't one Unix, there are several different vendors so you'd have to pick one.

Answer (score 3):

Agree with blihp and Jeff Schaller, having done lots of consulting and managed a few data centers... when you say "Unix proper", what do you mean? AT&T system V? True64? The one true unix?

If you want POSIX certfied, that is one thing, install an OS from the list on [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX). If you want to learn "unix", there is more help in installing some variant of Linux than any other "unix" out there, IMHO.

Comment: The only Linux distribution I found mentioned on that page is Android. That sounds odd, I wouldn't have expected Android to be the most POSIX compliant among Linux distributions.

Comment: @kasperd not that odd, if you know who made Android, and what are [yearly fees](http://get.posixcertified.ieee.org/register.html) required to obtain and hold POSIX certification...

Comment: @MatijaNalis It doesn't say Android is certified it just says it is compliant. That means the fees don't matter. But on a second look I realize it does say that most Linux distributions are POSIX compliant. Android just happens to be the only distribution mentioned explicitly, which is redundant since it already says most Linux distributions are POSIX compliant.

Comment: @kasperd it only says Linux (and as a result, Android) are *mostly* compliant.  They have minor (mostly?) deliberate differences.  I would argue that today it's more important to be Linux compatible than POSIX compliant.

Comment: @blihp I agree that these days it is probably more important to be compatible with Linux than with POSIX. I haven't come across any of the traditional UNIX systems since 2011. I wonder if those have lost most of their market shares to Linux. OS X still has enough market share to be relevant, but it probably has been overtaken by Linux by now if we count both desktop, server, and embedded deployments. Lack of certification does not necessarily imply incompatible though. In terms of user space I would expect Android to be less compatible than most other Linux distributions.

Comment: @kasperd agree and similar situation here re: it being a while since seeing traditional Unix.  Aside from OS X, you won't see it in startups / small companies anymore the way it was (esp. Solaris) all over the place in the 90's and early 00's.  They've mostly gone to Linux.  You'll still see it in large enterprises the way you'll still find mainframes there and probably will find both for decades to come for legacy projects.  Linux isn't incompatible because it's not certified, it's incompatible because specific decisions were deliberately made to be. (but only in minor ways currently)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course

I tried [OpenSolaris](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenSolaris) once when it was still free. Nowadays it's not available anymore but you can still use various variants and forks of it like [OpenIndiana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenIndiana), [OmniOS](https://omniosce.org/) and [illumos](https://illumos.org/). See [Open Solaris derivatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenSolaris#Derivatives) and [illumos Distributions](https://illumos.org/docs/about/distro/)

If you don't mind using a closed-source OS then **Solaris 11 is still free** for *"developing, testing, prototyping and demonstrating your applications"* as [per its license](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/licenses/solaris-cluster-express-license-167852.html). Oracle also provides [ready-made VMs](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/solaris11/downloads/vm-templates-2245495.html) for use

Note that there are many [Unix-like operating systems that are not Linux](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/3-unix-like-operating-systems-arent-linux/), and there are [some Linux distros that are Unix-certified](https://github.com/sirredbeard/Awesome-UNIX#unix-certified-linux-based-operating-systems) like [Inspur K-UX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inspur_K-UX) and [Huawei EulerOS](https://www.huawei.com/en/press-events/news/2016/9/huawei-kunlun-euleros-unix-certification)

You can find more Unix OSes [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_UNIX_Specification#Compliance). Most of them work only if you have money though, or at least work/study in an organization that has a real Unix system

## Update:

Huawei has just [released a community edition of EulerOS](https://itsfoss.com/openeuler/) called [openEuler](https://openeuler.org/en/). You can download and install it

Comment: While Solaris is a true UNIX, OpenIndiana is not.

Comment: OpenIndiana is a fork (as in a copy of the source code) of OpenSolaris, how is that not UNIX ?

Comment: @thecarpy because UNIX is a [registered trademark of The Open Group](http://www.unix.org/trademark.html) and you are only allowed by law the use that name in relation of approved products (that pay for the priviledge). Hence the use of **UN*X**, **unixoid**, **UNIX-alike OS** etc.

Comment: @MatijaNalis: In my country (and I suspect in most countries), trademarks only restrict, you know, "trade". I can call something "UNIX" as much as I want, as long as I don't compete (in a broad sense) with The Open Group.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Trademark law is in vast majority of countries **way** more complicated than such simplistic linguistic parsing of word "trademark". _[A registered trademark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trademark#Registration) confers a bundle of exclusive rights upon the registered owner, including the right to exclusive use of the mark in relation to the products or services for which it is registered. (in same [Nice classification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_(Nice)_Classification_of_Goods_and_Services))_. So you may not call your OS "UNIX" unless you have permission.

Comment: @forest just find out that Solaris 11 is still free, so you can actually use a true UNIX

Comment: @phuclv It's free as in gratis, but not as in libre.

Comment: who cares? What I want is the ability to install, not the access to its source code